# Can I make new nautilus create tabs, instead of making new windows?

Tags: nautilus

When I connect my external drive, which has 4 partition, it opens 4 nautilus windows. When I connect a pen-drive, it opens another one for that. Is there a way that new windows will create a tab in an open instance of nautilus, and if there isn't any instance open, create a new one, and open further windows in that.

Thanks.

Comment: *sighs*  I really wish this were possible, and really don't get why this isn't a config/setting in nautilus by this point.  Why even have tabs if you can't enforce them, since you're going to accidentally end up with multiple windows with a few windows having tabs anyway.

Comment: if you use [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh) script with `--autoopentabs` option, it will close all nautilus windows and mix them all in a single new window with tabs!

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to use middle-click to open tabs. It can't be made default yet.

Comment: This should be the right answer!
Unfortunately it's not possible to split their views  in the same window

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know this is not available in Nautilus, however as an alternative you can install PCMan File Manager from the software centre which supports tabs [here is a link](http://pcmanfm.sourceforge.net/) to their homepage which has all the details

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus in natty alpha 2 has open in new tab on the right click menu.